# Typescript not recognizing that yield keyword is in a generator function or generator body

Tags: typescript, generator, yield

This is my generator function:

```
function* generatorFunction(input: number[]): IterableIterator<number> {
  input.forEach((num) => {
    yield num;
  });
```

This is the linting error:

`A 'yield' expression is only allowed in a generator body.ts(1163)`

What is typescript expecting?

**Additional info:**

*Typescript versions*

```
"typescript": "^4.2.3"
"@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^4.19.0",
"@typescript-eslint/parser": "^4.19.0",
```

*tsconfig.json*

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es6",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "declaration": true,
    "strict": true,
    "noImplicitAny": true /* Raise error on expressions and declarations with an implied 'any' type. */,
    "strictNullChecks": true /* Enable strict null checks. */,
    "strictFunctionTypes": true /* Enable strict checking of function types. */,
    "noUnusedLocals": true /* Report errors on unused locals. */,
    "noUnusedParameters": true /* Report errors on unused parameters. */,
    "noImplicitReturns": true /* Report error when not all code paths in function return a value. */,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true /* Report errors for fallthrough cases in switch statement. */,
    "importHelpers": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "outDir": "./dist/tsc/",
    "types": [
      "node",
      "jest"
    ],
    "lib": [
      "ES6",
      "DOM"
    ]
  },
  "include": [
    "src/**/*.ts"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "**/*.test.ts"
  ]
}
```

Comment: That's *not* in the generator body, it's in the (non-generator) _callback_.

Comment: Have you tried `function* generatorFunction(input: number[]): Generator { ... }`?

Comment: @SethLutske Yes, I tried replacing `IterableIterator<number>` with `Generator` but I still get the error.

Comment: @jonrsharpe thanks for the hint, but it seems like the yield keyword needs to go into the callback, am I wrong?

Comment: That's where the value you want to yield is, but syntactically it can't. So you need to think of another way of looping.

Comment: Its common to use a `while` loop within generators, that might do the trick

Comment: Using a while loop works like this.
```function* generatorFunction(
  input: number[]
): IterableIterator<number | undefined> {
  while (input.length) {
    yield input.pop();
  }
}```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason yield is not recognized is because you are calling yield inside a non generator function. It is important to realize you are not calling yield within this function.

```
function* generatorFunction(input: number[]): IterableIterator<number> {
 }
```

But rather calling yield inside this function

```
(num) => {
   
}
```

Since this function is not a generator function you are getting that error.

To fix this use a loop instead of an array iterator function.

The code should look something like this instead

```
function* generatorFunction(input: number[]): IterableIterator<number> {
  for(let i = 0; i < input.length; i++){
     yield input[i];
  }
}
```

Comment: Didn't appreciate that the forEach statement made a callback, removing yiled from the body. In addition to your for loop, a while loop works too ```Using a while loop works like this. function* generatorFunction(   input: number[] ): IterableIterator<number | undefined> {   while (input.length) {     yield input.pop();   } }```